# How can China put artificial moon if they're not in equator?

Tags: rocket-science, space-mission

China plan to put artificial moon.

I suppose the moon would have to be geo stationary in orbit. However, a geostationary orbit would be on equator and china is not on equator.

So how would it work? Will the artificial moon be on top of Shanghai only at night? What?

Comment: http://www.astronomy.com/news/2018/10/why-chinas-artificial-moon-probably-wont-work

Answer (score 0):

The "artificial moon" would only need to be a large, flat, steerable mirror in *geosynchronous* orbit.  In this case, the mirror would always adjust its tilt angle to reflect sunlight toward Shanghai.  Note that the entire mirror would not need to be tilted; it could be an array of small flat mirrors that are individually steerable.

Comment: So the moon will be in equator?

Comment: Not exactly.  A geosynchronous orbit is tilted relative to the equator, so from the ground it looks as if the satellite is moving in a "figure 8" path.